# SQL left join and manual null addition

Tags: sql

I have tables(columns) `A(a)` and `B(b, a)`.
Field `a` is primary in `A`, `b` is primary in `B`. `A` represents a set of classes, `B` represents a set of elements, each of them is part of one class.
The task is to retrieve all the classes (`A.a`) is first column and elements of those classes in second column. If some class does not contain elements, it should be retrieved with null in second column.

Right query is:

```
select A.a, B.b from A left join B on A.a = B.a
```

This does exactly what I need. But, having read the documentation of left join, I tried to repeat this result manually with query:

```
select B.a, B.b as "b" from B
union
select A.a, null as "b" from A
where A.a not in (select B.a from B)
```

First line selects all the pairs I need, 3rd-4th lines select specifically those classes which are not presented in table `B` with null in second column.
Those two queries return different number of rows, and I do not understand why. Could somebody explain me that? Is it something with my understanding of left joining behaviour or something else?
(Unfortunately, I do not have much access to the server I performed it on, I may only see the number of rows returned.)

Comment: This is not the same thing. For entities that are in both `A` and `B` based on the `a` value, the join will return rows that are a combinations of values from `A` and `B`. `union` can never give you that - it is essentially a concatenation of rows.

Comment: Hm, union part is just a tail in my selection. Actually, if all values from A were presented in B table, I would expect both queries work the same way even if I removed last three lines from second query. But since some `a` may be missing from `B`, I concatenate those with union.

Comment: Is it definite that `B.a` is always set to some value? If some rows do not have a value (i.e. if they have NULL) in `B.a`, only the first part of the second query can return rows and the second part can get nothing. Also, is the foreign key from B to A actually defined, so as to guarantee that wrong references cannot be stored in `B.a`?

Comment: Interesting version, but if `B.a` was null sometimes, the second query would return more rows than the first one, wouldn't it? Actually it returns less. My fault I did not specify that.

Comment: It is possible for the second query to return fewer rows in the case of nulls. If there are few rows with nulls in `B.a` and there are many rows in `A` not referenced by any `B` row, [the first query can return more rows than the second one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b635/1).

Comment: I think it is the issue. A pity: I did not know about the `not in (null)` behaviour, that's why I didn't understand you at first. So, basically, I just posted my question wrongly and confused everybody. If you copy your comment as answer, I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*(Note: this was first posted as a comment.)*</sub>

If `B.a` can have NULLs and some rows do have NULLs in that column, the second query's second part will return nothing. That is because `x NOT IN (list)` essentially translates to

```
 x <> value1 AND x <> value2 AND ...
```

and when at least one of the values is NULL, that particular `<>` predicate evaluates to UNKNOWN and, in case all other predicates have evaluated to TRUE, the entire condition becomes UNKNOWN too (TRUE AND UNKNOWN yields UNKNOWN, according to [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)).

Depending on the ratio between `B` rows with NULLs in `B.a` and `A` rows not referenced by any `B` row, the entire second query can return [more](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/906a5/1) or [fewer rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0cf0/6) than the first query, although it is possible for the two queries to return [same number of rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2188/1) too.

One other possibility is presence of references to non-existent `A` rows in `B` (which implies absence of a foreign key to guarantee referential integrity). If there are such rows, the first query will return [fewer rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/714ff/1) than the second one, because it will exclude invalid references, while the second query will include them.

Answer (score 0):

Union will treat all null values as a single null value and that may not be what you are expecting. There are two ways around this:

```
1. Use UNION ALL
2. Use non distinct "type Fields"...


    SELECT
          Type="Type1",
          Amount
       FROM 
         Table

       UNION

       SELECT
          Type="Type2",
          Amount
       FROM 
          Table
```

Comment: I do not actually understand the meaning of "treat as a single null value". Both queries should not and do not(?) return any identical rows. Right part of union has null in second column, but all different values in first one. That is because A.a and B.b both are unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have data like this:

```
Table A
1
2
3
4

Table B
1, A
1, B
2, A
3, F
3, F
```

The `UNION` will eliminate any duplicate results that occur. In this case, the "3, F" is listed only once. The results will otherwise be identical. A `UNION ALL` should return the same exact results.

See this [SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a36c/2/1)

Comment: I doubt it is the case, since the field which you filled with letters, is primary key in table B. So, duplicates are not possible.